# How do i write my sql query to split a column?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table in MySQL like

---

```
 aaa 1234555 asdasdvad
 asdasdada 4564456 as
 asdadw 8547965 asdasdasd
_________________________
```

And i want to split it two column by splitting numbers and letter which is like

```
   t1                     t2
_________________   _______________
aaa asdasdvad          1234555
asdasdada as           4564456
asdadw asdasdasd       8547865
```

How do i write a sql query to do that

any help would be appreciated

Comment: You need to tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: what you have tried for that?

Comment: i tried to use substring_index and regexp together but i failed all the time and i confused

Comment: Is every entry in the column a text word, followed by a number, followed by another text word?

Comment: if we think there are a lot of record, numbers can be end of the string  and its better writing a query like that, i am just trying to learn

Answer (score 1):

We can do this using `SUBSTRING_INDEX` without too much trouble:

```
SELECT
    CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(col, ' ', 1), ' ', SUBSTRING_INDEX(col, ' ', -1)) AS t1,
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(col, ' ', 2), ' ', -1) AS t2
FROM yourTable;
```

[image]

### Demo

But, this answer really just assumes that you want the first and third term concatenated together as one column, and the middle term as the second column.  I make no effort to check for numbers, letters, etc.